# Can I start AsyncTask in a fragment before creating the view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

How early can I start an AsyncTask in the Fragment lifecycle if **I need `onCreateView()` to run before `onPostExecute()`**? I know I could just start the AsyncTask in `onCreateView()` but I'm wondering if there is any guarantee that the UI thread will reach a certain point before handing any completed background tasks. What causes the UI thread to transition to the AsyncTask upon completion?

Comment: onAttach() and onCreate() start before onCreateView()

Answer (score 1):

**How early can I start an AsyncTask in the Fragment lifecycle**

you can start the AsyncTask in the onCreate() but it doesn't matter.

**What causes the UI thread to transition to the AsyncTask upon completion?**

AsyncTask uses a handler to update the UI, which means that it sends a message to the queue of the UI thread to be executed some time in the future. Although you can't know when that will happen, in your case it will almost always be executed after the set up of the fragment.

Comment: I added emphasis to a key part of my question. I need to know if "almost always" can be a guarantee.

Comment: I can put it in bold but that's what it is. Almost always. You can t know. What you can is change the logic of your code. If it is mandatory to execute the onpost execute before the fragment UI is created, do it in the activity before you add the fragment or in the previous event/screen.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no guarantee for this because AsyncTask is supposed to run asynchronously and you cannot predict when it should run.

You can however control this behavior by executing AsyncTask before instantiating fragment and simply pass AsyncTask result to your fragment. This approach makes sense because if you want to run it before the invocation of onCreateView() you might not need fragment's state  or instance variable in it.